# Python DRF, extracting serialized data to a variable

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've using python for a while now and I wanted to convert a desktop project to an API using the Django rest framework.

This is the first API that I'm building so It's all relatively new to me.

I'm trying to receive data from the user, run some logic with it and return an HTML page(folium map).

I've created a Model to receive the relevant data from the user.

```py
from django.db import models


class PostGDT1AndUAV(models.Model):
    """
    POST user's GDT1 and UAV locations.
    """

    latitude_gdt = models.FloatField(name='LatitudeGDT1',
                                     unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                     help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                     default=1)
    longitude_gdt = models.FloatField(name='LongitudeOfGDT1',
                                      unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                      help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google "
                                                "Maps.",
                                      default=1)

    latitude_uav = models.FloatField(name='LatitudeOfUAV',
                                     unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                     help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google "
                                               "Maps.",
                                     default=1)
    longitude_uav = models.FloatField(name='LongitudeOfUAV',
                                      unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                      help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google "
                                                "Maps.",
                                      default=1)
```

And I wrote a serializer for the data:

I just don't get how to utilize the serializers, I understand the concept of them, used to convert the data to a more readable and usable format, I just don't understand how I get the data from the user, run it through my code and send back the response and where in the project should my logical code be (the views?)

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import PostGDT1AndUAV


class PostGDT1AndUAVSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostGDT1AndUAV
        fields = ('latitude_gdt', 'longitude_gdt', 'latitude_uav', 'longitude_uav')


gdt1_data = PostGDT1AndUAVSerializer(PostGDT1AndUAV).to_representation()
print(gdt1_data)
```

I know it's a few questions and general but I scanned the entire docs and several tutorials and still hadn't find my way in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a model instance or an iterable of model instances to the serializer:

```
post_instance = PostGDT1AndUAV.objects.get(id=1)

# Returns {'latitude_gdt': ..., 'longitude_gdt': ..., 'latitude_uav': ..., 'longitude_uav': ...}
PostGDT1AndUAVSerializer(post_instance).data
```

---

```
post_instances = PostGDT1AndUAV.objects.filter(...)

# Returns [{'latitude_gdt': ... }, {'latitude_gdt': ... }, ... ]
PostGDT1AndUAVSerializer(post_instances, many=True).data
```

Check out the serialization section of the tutorial: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers

It goes over all your questions.